# is there an API in iText 7 to add a cell at a specific position?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

is there a way in iText 7 to add a cell at a specific position? Say table is defined with 3 rows and 2 columns(currently API supports table creation only with noOfColumn), now can we map a cell to 3rd row and 2nd column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achive that using below code.
table.getCell(3, 2).add(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("test")));

Comment: In this case, we need to create an empty cell and retrieve the cell via position and add it. how to clear the data in the cell if already exists?